# TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I am working with the angular--fullstack generator, and everything has ran smoothly until now. I do not know what I changed, but now my server task is halted by this error.

```
/Users/User/APP/server/config/express.js:28
secret: _environment2.default.secrets.session,
                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined
at Object.exports.default (express.js:41:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:23:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at loader (/Users/User/APP/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/User/APP/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:168:7)
at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/User/APP/server/index.js:12:28)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
```

Here is my express.js up to app.use(session({}):

```
/**
* Express configuration
*/

'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import favicon from 'serve-favicon';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import compression from 'compression';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import methodOverride from 'method-override';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import errorHandler from 'errorhandler';
import path from 'path';
import lusca from 'lusca';
import config from './environment';
import passport from 'passport';
import session from 'express-session';
import sqldb from '../sqldb';
import expressSequelizeSession from 'express-sequelize-session';
var Store = expressSequelizeSession(session.Store);

export default function(app) {
var env = app.get('env');

app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(compression());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
// Persist sessions with MongoStore / sequelizeStore
// We need to enable sessions for passport-twitter because it's an
// oauth 1.0 strategy, and Lusca depends on sessions
app.use(session({
secret: config.secrets.session,
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: false,
store: new Store(sqldb.sequelize)
}));
```

And here is my index.js for config/environment:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var _ = require('lodash');

function requiredProcessEnv(name) {
if (!process.env[name]) {
throw new Error('You must set the ' + name + ' environment variable');
}
return process.env[name];
}

// All configurations will extend these options
// ============================================
var all = {
env: process.env.NODE_ENV,

// Root path of server
root: path.normalize(__dirname + '/../../..'),

// Server port
port: process.env.PORT || 9000,

// Server IP
ip: process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0',

// Should we populate the DB with sample data?
seedDB: false,

// Secret for session, you will want to change this and make it an  environment variable
secrets: {
session: process.env.session || "wav"
},
// Export the config object based on the NODE_ENV
// ==============================================
module:exports = _.merge(
all,
require('./shared'),
require('./' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js') || {})};
```

UPDATE: With the addition of
 `var config = _.merge(...); console.log(config); module.exports = config;` on the last line of the index.js, the error now is regarded in syntax. Error:
    `line 39 col 7 Expected ':' and instead saw '.'.
 line 42 col 3 Unexpected 'var'. 
line 42 col 3 Expected an identifier and instead saw 'var'. 
line 42 col 7 Expected ')' and instead saw 'config'. 
line 42 col 14 Bad assignment. 
line 42 col 27 Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
 line 42 col 27 Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'. 
line 42 col 28 Expected ')' and instead saw ';
line 42 col 30 Expected '}' to match '{' from line 15 and instead saw 'console'. 
line 42 col 42 'config' is not defined. line 42 col 68 'config' is not defined.`

Comment: The error's pretty clear? `environment2.default` has no property `secrets`, so find out where that's *supposed* to be set, and find out why that's not happening properly. For instance, you should be suspicious of that `_.merge`, it's probably not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I understand what the error is, but I do not know how to resolve. I do not have any files, folders, variables, etc.. names environment2.default. My only solution would be to make the secrets in index.js an environment variable. Do you think that would suffice ?

Comment: Nothing here has been changed, but seemingly "all of sudden" this morning I keep getting this error.

Comment: the `environment2` name is a red herring, due to using babel etc. You want to find the part where you're passing what *should* have a "secrets" property into express, because that's the first place things can go wrong. Change that very last line to `var config = _.merge(...); console.log(config); module.exports = config;` and see what's *actually* in it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I tried that and several variations, to no avail unfortunately. I keep getting syntax errors that seem a little bogus. Will still persist.

Comment: it's not a good idea to put all of this in the comments - you're not debugging "for me", you're debugging "for everyone", because someone else might also be able to comment on your post and they'll need to know where you are with this. So, update your post if you have new information instead. It looks like you made some changes to one or more files involving some bad syntax.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have updated, I do apologize. I have not made any edits to any of the files, as when I leave it the way it is I only get the session read error.

Comment: in that case it's a good idea to remove the comments with the debug results - it's probably also worth taking the code you have now, copying it to a new dir, and then forming an [mcve](/help/mcve), especially here given that your error seems unrelated to the vast majority of the imports you're using, so to make sure others can help you reduce the code until it can run standalone, while still exhibiting the problem. Quite often while doing this actually find the error yourself, which makes mcves a powereful debugging technique (either you find it, or others will now be able to much easier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is found and discussed here: [Syntax Error in Index.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144585/syntax-error-in-index-js/37145241#37145241) . The type error resulted from an underlying syntax error.