# Syntax Error in Index.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql, express, vs-web-application-project

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var _ = require('lodash');

function requiredProcessEnv(name) {
if (!process.env[name]) {
throw new Error('You must set the ' + name + ' environment variable');
}
return process.env[name];
}

// All configurations will extend these options
// ============================================
var all = {
env: process.env.NODE_ENV,

// Root path of server
root: path.normalize(__dirname + '/../../..'),

// Server port
port: process.env.PORT || 9000,

// Server IP
ip: process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0',

// Should we populate the DB with sample data?
seedDB: false,

// Secret for session, you will want to change this and make it an  environment variable
secrets: {
session: process.env.session || "wav"
},
// Export the config object based on the NODE_ENV
// ==============================================
module.exports = _.merge(
all,
require('./shared'),
require('./' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js') || {})};
```

When ran with my project (web app created with angular-fullstack), I receive the following error :

```
Line 39 col 6 Unexpected token: module.exports
                                        ^
line 39  col 7   Expected ':' and instead saw '.'.
  line 42  col 54  Expected '}' to match '{' from line 15 and instead saw ';'.
```

Also, this code here also caused me some other problems in my project. I changed last few lines to :

```
var config = _.merge(...); 
  console.log(config); 
  module.exports = config;`
And I still get a syntax error: ` line 39  col 7   Expected ':' and instead saw 'config'.
  line 39  col 14  Expected an identifier and instead saw '='.
  line 39  col 16  Expected '}' to match '{' from line 15 and instead saw '_'.
  line 39  col 27  Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
  line 39  col 27  Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
  line 39  col 28  Expected ')' and instead saw ';'.
  line 40  col 15  'config' is not defined.
  line 41  col 20  'config' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'module.export' is inside 'all' object, moving it outside should work:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var _ = require('lodash');

function requiredProcessEnv(name) {
    if (!process.env[name]) {
        throw new Error('You must set the ' + name + ' environment variable');
    }
    return process.env[name];
}

// All configurations will extend these options
// ============================================
var all = {
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV,

// Root path of server
    root: path.normalize(__dirname + '/../../..'),

// Server port
    port: process.env.PORT || 9000,

// Server IP
    ip: process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0',

// Should we populate the DB with sample data?
    seedDB: false,

// Secret for session, you will want to change this and make it an  environment variable
    secrets: {
        session: process.env.session || "wav"
    }
};

// Export the config object based on the NODE_ENV
// ==============================================
module.exports = _.merge(
    all,
    require('./shared'),
    require('./' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js') || {}
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had noticed such a small thing. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Please learn to indent your code properly. Your error should then be crystal clear to find.

[Coding Style Guide for node.js apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495984/coding-style-guide-for-node-js-apps)

https://github.com/felixge/node-style-guide

Comment: np, indent it, then if you fail again, post again to see if we can help.